# MySQL Schema loses tables when I connect it to local host

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm working with MySQL Workbench 6.0. I built a schema from a .sql file. It has 1024 tables. when I connect it to local host only 47 tables seem to make it. I check with this command

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = "my_schema";
```

Why would it just leave behind the other 977 tables? is it a memory allocation thing? or an issue with my configuration?

**Edit 1**

result from the MySQL command

```
SHOW ENGINES;
```

[image: show engines sql result]

**Edit 2**

I checked out the .ini file that my local connection looks at. It uses the default one in

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6
```

This is its content of my-default.ini

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....


# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

so because this is the file its reading and I've not made any changes is there a memory issue for a database that has the large number of tables like mine? Or should I be leaving this allone for my local connection and be changing the settings through MySQL Workbench?

**Edit 3**

Blow is the results of SQL command

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

[image: show grants result]

Comment: Show it. We've read longer things here

Answer (score 0):

First confirm that sql file has all 1024 tables.

Second check that the engine of tables in sql file is present or not in your database server with command `SHOW ENGINES:`

Comment: The SQL file has all 1024 tables, It loads the schema into MySQL workbench with no problem, I see all 1024 tables in the schema on there. its when I connect that Schema to a local host on MySQL workbench that I get only 47 tables.